# CMD ... IF !first_char! == "." ( echo ...) ELSE () (IF test character comparaison do not work !)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo

for %%f in (*.lnk) do (
    set x=%%f
    echo !x!

    set first_char= "!x:~0,1!"
    echo !first_char! 


    IF !first_char! == "." ( 
        echo "first char is a dot"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "first char is NOT a dot"
    )
)
PAUSE
```

My files start with a dot and this windows cmd .bat programme echo allway "first char is NOT a dot"
so there is a problem surely with the IF interpretation.

Can someone figure it out ?

Comment: You already use `echo !first_char!` --- What do you see? Did you ever see a single dot? No, you see `<space>"."`

Comment: Given a file name, `.shortcut.lnk`, what do you think this line does, `set first_car= "!x:~0,1!"`? _It sets `%first_car%` to a value of `<space><doublequote><dot><doublequote>`._

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand now !

the correct way is :

```
rem no space after equal and no need double quote
    set first_char=!x:~0,1! 
rem and this IF will work perfect 
    IF !first_char! == . (
```

Fine thanks for your help.

Comment: `Set "first_char=!x:~0,1!"` and `If "!first_char!" == "." (` would be the correct syntax. Or reduce the unnecessary lines and do it as one `If "!x:~,1!" == "." (`